# How do I schedule a JBoss task?

Tags: jboss, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled task in JBoss:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <server>  
  <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler" name="acme:service=Scheduler">  
   <attribute name="...">...</attribute>  
   .....
  </mbean>  
 </server>
```

How to write this task, that will execute at 1:00 AM on the first day of every month? 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a scheduling class. [org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Scheduling_Tasks-org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler_.html)

Since you want to perform monthly and cannot state this as a attribute. You'll need to have another Class which handles setting the next interval.  [Java Monthly Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107011/java-monthly-timer)

Have the scheduler class call the monthly timer to get the next interval and set it. Maybe pass some values at initial start.

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler"
       name="jboss.docs:service=Scheduler">
    <attribute name="StartAtStartup">true</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableClass">org.jboss.book.misc.ex2.ExSchedulable</attribute>
    <attribute name="SchedulableArguments">01:00</attribute> <!-- 24hr time hh:mm -->
    <attribute name="SchedulableArgumentTypes">java.lang.String</attribute>

</mbean>
```

ExSchedulable (this is just pseudo-code)

```
public ExSchedulable(String time)  {
    Date tDate = new Date();
    tDate.setTime(time);

    Monthly monthyObj = Monthly(1); //Day of the month
    //Gets the next interval date specified from the day of the month 
    Date nextInterval = monthyObj .getNextInterval(tDate); 

}
```